# gerrit: cannot access the settings page

Tags: gerrit

The problem is that the `settings` page cannot be accessed. I sign in successfully by using the default administrator account `admin`. It redirected me to the login page and clikcing on the account showed the login page again.

The version is `3.2.2`. The `auth.type` is `DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT` since it is configured for a test environment. The access to the gerrit-sshd is successful. Details about the gerrit-config file are given below.

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://10.7.225.79:7000/
    serverId = a741248c-d502-4a4d-aed8-188ca2b8be36
[container]
    javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackendFactory#getInstance"
    javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"
    user = gerrit
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[index]
    type = lucene
[auth]
    type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
[receive]
    enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:7000/
[cache]
    directory = cache
[plugins]
    allowRemoteAdmin = true
```

the information about version is given below:

```
# java
# command: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~16.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

# gerrit
# command: ssh -p 29418 admin@10.7.225.79 gerrit version
gerrit version 3.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe this is the way things work when "DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT" is set.

Take a look at the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#auth) about this:

> DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
>
> DO NOT USE. Only for use in a development environment.
>
> When this is the configured authentication method a hyperlink titled
> Become appears in the top right corner of the page, taking the user to
> a form where they can enter the username of any existing user account,
> and immediately login as that account, without any authentication
> taking place.

Comment: I've read this before this post. Other options for the `auth` section will require another server. It leaves me no choice.

Comment: Why do you need another server if you use other option?

Comment: If using `HTTP`, a web server for the authentication is required. I can choose this 
 option if I find the guideline. If using `OpenID`, access to the Internet is required. If using `LDAP`, LDAP server is required. The  `DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT` option use the internal data from the gerrit server, doesnt it?

Comment: I understand, so you're just doing some tests, right? Or are you developing something? Anyway, you could consider installing the OpenLDAP (https://www.openldap.org/).

Comment: Basically, I need to run the gerrit-server and test its functionality for better integration.  However, one malware is the settings about user, which will cause the authentication issue when using gerrit-api.

Comment: Are you trying to homologate Gerrit? It should be better if you use it with any valid authentication method, shouldn't it?